# Service Fabric behavior in a real distributed system

Tags: azure-service-fabric

By "real" I mean with vehicles and clients in remote  locations where you may get 4-24 hours comms outages regularly or have links go down to 20-30kb?

How is concurrency handled , what happens if 2 services in a cluster split from the  3rd due to a comms outage  ?

Note a key business requirement is aggregating the data for a global view.

Comment: Are you talking about a Service Fabric cluster that spans areas with machines that have limited connectivity?

Comment: yes. More specifically how the actors  replicate state.  Im thinking its more a back end solution and you need to synch data from clients to a central repository yourself ( or face severe locking issues) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the way you phrased the question, it sounds like you might be assuming that Service Fabric's data replication capabilities would span to the occasionally-connected clients, which is not the case. Typically, you would set up a cluster (either in Azure or on-prem) where the nodes have generally reliable connectivity to each other. The platform is resilient to some of those nodes becoming unavailable or very slow due to network problems by ensuring that transactions are acknowledged by a quorum of other nodes in the cluster.

How you get the data from the clients into the services running in the cluster is up to you - most people just expose a REST API.